# Three masses with 2 springs in 1D

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, linear-systems, coupled-oscillators

Consider three arbitrary masses attached by two different springs in vacuum, starting at arbitrary initial positions with no initial velocities. Is this system chaotic? Is this system analytically solvable? Why or why not?

If solvable, is there an equivalent to the three-body problem in 1D, preferably with linear springs?

```
         [m1]--MWMW-k12-MWMW--[m2]--MW-k23-MW--[m3]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem has an analytical solution if one can find the eigenvalues of a 3×3 matrix. Let me elaborate.

Without loss of generality define a coordinate system at the combined center of mass such that

$$ m_1 x_1 + m_2 x_2 + m_3 x_3 =0$$ at all times. Additionally, the coordinate origin must have steady speed (inertial frame) such that also at all times $$ m_1 \dot{x}_1 + m_2 \dot{x}_2 + m_3 \dot{x}_3 =0$$

Now consider the displacements in a vector

$$ X = \pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3} $$

This leads to the following second-order ODE with three equations

$$\underbrace{ \begin{bmatrix} m_1 \\ & m_2 \\ & & m_3 \end{bmatrix} }_M \tfrac{{\rm d}^2}{{\rm d}t^2} X(t) 
 + \underbrace{ \begin{bmatrix} k_{12} & -k_{12} & 0 \\ -k_{12} & k_{12}+k_{23} & -k_{23} \\ 0 & -k_{23} & k_{23}  \end{bmatrix} }_K X(t) = \pmatrix{0\\0\\0} $$

Define the combined 3×3 matrix $A = M^{-1} K$ and re-write the above as

$$ \ddot{X} + A X = 0 $$

Transform the above using the 3 eigenvalues of $\mathrm{eig}(A)=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)$ and arrange them in diagonal matrix $\Lambda = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 \\ & \lambda_2 \\ & & \lambda_3 \end{bmatrix}$ as well the the three eigenvectors as the columns of a matrix $\Phi = \begin{bmatrix} \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ v_1 & v_2 & v_2 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \end{bmatrix}$.

This arrangement leads to the following decomposition of $A$ and $X$

$$ A = \Phi \, \Lambda \, \Phi^{-1} $$

$$ X = \Phi\, U $$

where $U = \pmatrix{u_1 \\ u_2 \\ u_3}$ is the vector ofcontributions of each eigenvector to the solution.

The ODE is then diagonalized as follows

$$ \underbrace{ \Phi \ddot{U}}_{\ddot{X}} + \underbrace{ (\Phi \Lambda \Phi^{-1})}_{A} \,\underbrace{(\Phi U)}_{X} = 0 $$

$$ \Phi \left( \ddot{U} + \Lambda\, U \right) = 0 $$

Since $\Lambda$ is diagonal the above is the following de-coupled 3 ODE equations

$$ \begin{aligned} 
 \ddot{u}_1 + \lambda_1\, u_1 & = 0 \\
 \ddot{u}_2 + \lambda_2\, u_2 & = 0 \\
 \ddot{u}_3 + \lambda_3\, u_3 & = 0 \\
\end{aligned} $$

with analytical solution (note that $\ddot{u} = - \omega^2 \,u$ is the SHM equation)

$$ \begin{aligned} 
 {u}_1(t) & = a_1 \sin(\sqrt{\lambda_1}\,t) + b_1 \cos(\sqrt{\lambda_1}\,t) \\
 {u}_2(t) & = a_2 \sin(\sqrt{\lambda_2}\,t) + b_2 \cos(\sqrt{\lambda_2}\,t) \\
 {u}_3(t) & = a_3 \sin(\sqrt{\lambda_3}\,t) + b_3 \cos(\sqrt{\lambda_3}\,t) \\
\end{aligned} $$

With the coefficients $a_i$ and $b_i$ determined by the initial conditions.

Once the vector $U$ is evaluated from above, so does the solution $X=\Phi \,U$.

It turns out the lowest eigenvalue of the above system is **zero** and if the coordinate system described above is used then $a_1=0$ and $b_1=0$, making the first solution to be $u_1(t) = 0$. This is called the rigid body motion solution, and it is often ignored, reducing the above problem into a more manageable 2×2 system of equations.

Given a set of initial conditions $X_0 = \pmatrix{x_1(0) \\ x_2(0) \\ x_3(0)}$, you work out the math and the $b_1$ coefficient is

$$  b_1 = \frac{\sqrt{3} ( m_1 x_1(0) + m_2 x_2(0) + m_3 x_3(0) )}{m_1+m_2+m_3} = 0 $$